# Is it possible to use an expandablelistview as a dropdownview for a spinner with multiple select?

Tags: android, spinner, expandablelistview

I am using a Button plus an AlertDialog containing an ExpandableListView.
Also put a checkbox along with child row, its working fine for single select, but its not waiting for multiple select.

When I am using for multiple select, I have to click outside the dialog to terminate the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I am answering my own question, now its working. I just use check and not check images to show sub category is selected or not.

Steps:

1. Create a button on toolbar/actionbar, make the UI like spinner.

   ```
   Button btn_filter = (Button)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.filters);
   btn_filter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           dialogFilter.show();
       }
   });
   ```
2. Create a alert dialog, set the x, y position just below the button.

   ```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialogFilter.getWindow().getAttributes();
   wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
   wmlp.x = 10;   //x position
   wmlp.y = 100;   //y position
   ```
3. Create classes (models) for category and sub category and add data.

   ```
   public class FilterCategory {
       public String category_name = null;
       public ArrayList<SubCategory> subcategory_array = new  ArrayList<SubCategory>();
   }
   public class SubCategory {
        public String subcategory_name = null;
        public boolean selected = false;
   }
   ```
4. Check for selected or nor selected.

   ```
      if(category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected) {
               category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected = false;
           } else {
               category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected = true;
           }
   ```
5. At last in Adapter

   ```
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean arg1, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
     GroupHolder groupHolder;

     if (view == null) {
      view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.group_row,null);
      groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
      groupHolder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_img);
      groupHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
      view.setTag(groupHolder);
     } else {
      groupHolder = (GroupHolder) view.getTag();
     }
     groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition).category_name);
     if(arg1){
          groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dropdown_small_arrow_converted);
      }else{
          groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_small_arrow_converted);
      }
       return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean arg2, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
       final ChildHolder childHolder;
     if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
      childHolder = new ChildHolder();
      childHolder.checkBox = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
      childHolder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.childname);
      convertView.setTag(childHolder);
     } else {
      childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
     childHolder.name.setText(mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).subcategory_name);

     if(mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected) {
      childHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
      childHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }

     return convertView;
    }
   ```

Screenshots:

Sorry I am not able to post screenshots, because needed at least 10 reputation to post image :(